# Filter the variable before exporting into an excel sheet

Tags: powershell

I am exporting the output of my script to a variable and then to the `.csv` file using `Export-Csv`.

```
$output | Export-Csv  $Param2
```

I need to filter the variable $output based on an array before exporting into to the csv.

I want to remove any lines in the variable match the array list below

```
@('*Monitoring*','*insxs*','*hp_manifest*','*winrm*')
```

Please let me know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$output` is an array of strings, this should do it

```
($output -notmatch 'Monitoring|insxs|hp_manifest|winrm') | Export-Csv  $Param2
```